# css3 keyframes transition not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have the below which is also available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/G7FPq/1/).

I want the background to move like it does in ff and ie but it isn't working in chrome for some reason?
Is it something I have done wrong or is something I included not supported in webkit?

```
    <div id="box"></div>

    @keyframes movingbg {
        from {
            background-position:0 0;
        }
        to {
            background-position:center center;
        }
    }

    #box {
        -webkit-animation-name: movingbg;
        -o-animation-name: movingbg;
        -ms-animation-name: movingbg;
        -moz-animation-name: movingbg;
        animation-name: movingbg;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        -o-animation-duration: 5s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/") no-repeat scroll center 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G7FPq/3/)

You have the vendor prefixes within the `ID`, but unfortunately you left them off of the keyframe call...

By simply adding this to your code to your CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes movingbg {
    from {
        background-position:0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position:center center;
    }
}
```

You can set up the animation to work within the `-webkit` browsers

Comment: Silly mistake I was focusing on the css not the key frame bit. Will be sure to invlude in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -webkit- for safari and chrome

```
@keyframes mymove
{
from {top:0px;}
to {top:200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {top:0px;}
to {top:200px;}
}
```

Hope this helps you :)